# 'navigationBar' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

Tags: create-react-app

I am working on a react-app that I just created but while I was testing it I received this error:

> 'navigationBar' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

I am trying to import a component into my `app.js` in my react app for example: 
`import navigationBar from  ./navigationBar`

*app.js:*

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import navigationBar from './navigationBar'

function App() {
     return (
       <div>
         hello world
         <navigationBar />
       </div>
     );
}

export default App;
```

*navigationBar.js:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class navigationBar extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    hey there
                </div>
            )
        }
}
```

Comment: Capitalize the name of your component `NavigationBar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags. So, even if you use `navigationBar`, it won't be considered as using the component.

Use capital letter to begin the component name and you should be fine like `NavigationBar`

Comment: What if I can't use capital letter at the beginning of the component name? I plan to use facebook's fbt (it's i18n framwork) but if I use any thing other than <fbt>, it will throw error at the building process.

Comment: From what I understand, babel's fbt plugin transplies fbt nodes before babel transpiles JSX. So, this should be fine.